# User defined function changing each value in an array

Tags: arrays, excel, function, vba

Below is my code for a simple mortality table blend. the mortality table is always an array with 106 values. Running this code results in a #value error and I can't figure out why.

```
Public Function MorBlend(Table1 As Variant, Blend As Double, Table2 As Variant) As Variant

Dim Table3 As Variant, int1 As Double
int1 = 0

Do While int1 <= 105

    Table3(int1) = Round(Table1(int1) * Blend / 1000000 + Table2(int1) * (1 - Blend) / 1000000, 6) * 1000000
    int1 = int1 + 1
Loop

MorBlend = Table3

End Function
```

Comment: It might help to know what `Table1`, `Blend`, and `Table2` are.

Comment: Are you trying to return an array to code, or is this to be used as a worksheet function?

Comment: In order for your `Table3(int1) = ...` line to work, you will need to declare `Table3` as an array, currently with a lower bound of 0, and an upper bound of at least whatever value `int1` will reach.  But if you are intending this to be a UDF, the lower bound will need to be 1 so you will need to initialise `int1` to `1`.

Comment: If `Table1` and `Table2` are single column ranges on a worksheet, then `table1(0)` may be referring to a header row containing text, rather than the first row of numeric data.  In addition, you need to size `Table 3`.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. Table1 and table2 are two mortality tables both with 106 values and blend is the percentage of table1 to be used in the blend.

Comment: I am using the function for return into another function. The two array inputs are defined arrays of all the mortality tables that could be used. I will try the suggested code below, thanks! I will look into adding error checks and ubound.

Comment: I amended my answer to have a version which is more "flexible", but which may cause issues if you attempted to use it as a UDF.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a UDF, this should be written as follows (or something similar):

```
Public Function MorBlend(Table1 As Variant, Blend As Double, Table2 As Variant) As Variant

    'Table3 needs to be a two dimensional array, with the first dimension
    'representing rows in the result, and the second dimension representing
    'columns in the result
    Dim Table3(1 To 106, 1 To 1) As Variant

    Dim Age As Integer

    For Age = 0 To 105
        Table3(Age + 1, 1) = Round(Table1(Age + 1) * Blend / 1000000 + Table2(Age + 1) * (1 - Blend) / 1000000, 6) * 1000000
    Next

    MorBlend = Table3
End Function
```

This function could then be used in cells C1:C106 (for instance) and entered as an array formula (press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>Enter</kbd> to enter the formula) as

`=MorBlend(A1:A106,.25,B1:B106)`

Note: If you want to allow for mortality (or other) tables that don't go from age 0 up to age 105, you would need to modify the code to make use of the `UBound` of the input arrays.  The code above is hard-coded to expect exactly 106 rates and includes no error-checking for cases where that is not what is passed in.

---

If you have no intention of using the function as a UDF, some of the array dimensioning can be less restrictive - i.e. you will be able to dimension the arrays to commence from 0 instead of 1, and you won't need to have a two-dimensional array.

```
Public Function MorBlend(Table1 As Variant, Blend As Double, Table2 As Variant) As Variant

    Dim Table3() As Variant
    ReDim Table3(LBound(Table1) To UBound(Table1)) As Variant

    Dim Age As Integer

    For Age = LBound(Table1) To UBound(Table1)
        Table3(Age) = Round(Table1(Age) * Blend / 1000000 + Table2(Age) * (1 - Blend) / 1000000, 6) * 1000000
    Next

    MorBlend = Table3
End Function
```

This version of the code could be used in a program such as the following:

```
Sub Main
    Range("D2:D107") = Application.Transpose(Mor("71 GAM (50M/50F)"))
End Sub

Public Function Mor(Table As String) As Variant
    Dim Tbl_71GAM_M50F50 As Variant
    Dim Tbl_71GAM_M As Variant
    Dim Tbl_71GAM_F As Variant
    'Load tables from Excel ranges (e.g. "Tbl_716AM_M" may be the name of
    '  B2:B107, and "Tbl_716AM_F" may be the name of C2:C107)
    Tbl_71GAM_M = Application.Transpose(Range("Tbl_716AM_M"))
    Tbl_71GAM_F = Application.Transpose(Range("Tbl_716AM_F"))
    'Create a merged table
    Tbl_71GAM_M50F50 = MorBlend(Tbl_71GAM_M, 0.5, Tbl_71GAM_F)
    If Table = "71 GAM Male" Then Mor = Tbl_71GAM_M
    If Table = "71 GAM Female" Then Mor = Tbl_71GAM_F
    If Table = "71 GAM (50M/50F)" Then Mor = Tbl_71GAM_M50F50
End Function
```

Or, if you want to invoke `Mor` as an array-UDF, you could use the following

```
Public Function Mor(Table As String) As Variant
    Dim Tbl_71GAM_M50F50 As Variant
    Dim Tbl_71GAM_M As Variant
    Dim Tbl_71GAM_F As Variant
    'Load tables from Excel ranges (e.g. "Tbl_716AM_M" may be the name of
    '  B2:B107, and "Tbl_716AM_F" may be the name of C2:C107)
    Tbl_71GAM_M = Application.Transpose(Range("Tbl_716AM_M"))
    Tbl_71GAM_F = Application.Transpose(Range("Tbl_716AM_F"))
    'Create a merged table
    Tbl_71GAM_M50F50 = MorBlend(Tbl_71GAM_M, 0.5, Tbl_71GAM_F)
    If Table = "71 GAM Male" Then Mor = Application.Transpose(Tbl_71GAM_M)
    If Table = "71 GAM Female" Then Mor = Application.Transpose(Tbl_71GAM_F)
    If Table = "71 GAM (50M/50F)" Then Mor = Application.Transpose(Tbl_71GAM_M50F50)
End Function
```

and enter an array formula such as `=Mor("71 GAM (50M/50F)") in, for instance, cells D2:D107.

(So many possibilities, so little space to show them all.)

Comment: Thanks! How can I call this `function` and allocate the result to an array in another function? I'm getting a `#value` error

Comment: Wait - when you said you were "using the function for return into another function" I thought you meant another VBA function.  But that wouldn't create a `#value` error.  If you are using at as a UDF, even though it is going into another Excel function (e.g. as `=MIN(MorBlend(A1:A106,.25,B1:B106),MorBlend(A1:A106,.5,B1:B106))`), then you will need to stick to my first version of the code.

Comment: Thanks. I'm trying to use the following:    Public Function Mor(Table As String) As Variant

Dim Tbl_Mor As Variant
Dim Tbl_71GAM_M50F50 As Variant

Tbl_71GAM_M50F50 = MorBlend(Tbl_71GAM_M, 0.5, Tbl_71GAM_F)

If Table = "71 GAM Male" Then Tbl_Mor = Tbl_71GAM_M
If Table = "71 GAM Female" Then Tbl_Mor = Tbl_71GAM_F
If Table = "71 GAM (50M/50F)" Then Tbl_Mor = Tbl_71GAM_M50F50

Mor = Tbl_Mor
End Function but your suggestions helped me very much thanks.